# Regarding GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, dll, getprocaddress

I have got MyDll.dll and its function defined as below

```
void pascal Myfunction(BOOL);
```

when I'm trying to use the function in another project i am unable get the address of the function with `GetProcAddress()`. Here is my code:

```
void callMyDll()
{
 HINSTANCE hDll;

 hDll=LoadLibrary(_T("MyDll.dll");

 if(hDll!=NULL)
 {
  cout<<"\n DLL Loaded \n";
 }
 else
  cout<<"\n DLL Not loaded\n"

 typedef void (__stdcall *MyFunction)(bool)

 Myfunction mf1 = (MyFunction) GetProcAddress(hDll, "MyFunction");

 if (mf1!=NULL)
  cout<<"\n Function Loaded Successfully \n";
 else
  cout<<"\n Function not loaded \n";

 FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

I'm getting output as:

```
DLL Loaded
Function not loaded
```

But when I'm trying with known DLLs like glut32.dll and its functions it is working fine.

I think it may be problem with its function like

```
void pascal MyFunction(BOOL);
```

Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: after the header files i have included this as

Comment: Did you remember to export the function?

Comment: Please show us the function declaration from the source code for your DLL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling and ensure the function is exported:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Myfunction(BOOL);
```

To view the exports from your DLL you can use `dumpbin.exe` utility that is shipped with Visual Studio:

```
dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS MyDll.dll
```

This will list the names of all exported symbols.

In addition to this do not have either of the following compiler switches specified:

```
Gz __stdcall calling convention: "Myfunction" would be exported as Myfunction@4
Gr __fastcall caling convention: "Myfunction" would be exported as @Myfunction@4
```

*Note: I think last symbol is dependent on compiler version but is still not just "Myfunction".*

Comment: The function is declared as `pascal` which is the same as `__stdcall` on x86 and so `__declspec(dllexport)` will decorate no matter what the compiler options are. So it's going to be `_Myfunction@4` unless a .def file is used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for pointing that out. I had omitted the `pascal` calling convention in my answer but maybe this is necessary for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The DLL export process is subject to name mangling and decoration. The long obsolete 16 bit `pascal` calling convention is equivalent to `stdcall` on 32 bit platforms.

First of all you should use `extern "C"` to specify C linkage and disable name mangling.

However, your function will still be subject to [name decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx). If you export it with `__declspec(dllexport)` then it will in fact be exported with the name `_Myfunction@4`. If you wish to export it by its true name then you need to use a .def file.

However, the possibility still remains that you did not export the function from the DLL at all. Use [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to check whether it was exported, and if so by what name.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `pascal` calling-convention? Perhaps that alters the names of symbols, and if so you might need to take that into account.

Comment: `pascal` is a 16 bit calling convention that is #define'd to `__stdcall` on 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is going to be decorated, so it will never be called `MyFunction`, its more likely `_MyFunction@4`. you can quickly check this using something like [dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429).

You can read up more on mangling [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), if you want to avoid mangling, you need to use a `def` file to specify symbol names (or ordinals).

Comment: It's unclear in the original post, but it appears that `extern "C"` is in use, which would prevent the function name from being mangled (provided the calling convention isn't being overridden) but I've asked for the exported function declaration just to be sure.

Comment: @AdamMaras: it would still get a convention prefix at minimum on windows (see my links), `extern "C"` just says that it must to C style decoration, but he's using C anyways, its redundant

Comment: Thanks a lot i can able to load the functions.. that's great

Comment: @srinivasporam: if its the right answer you should mark it as such (click the green tick next to the question)