# GetProcAddress unble to get adress which of the form Void pascal Myfunction(BOOL)

Tags: c++

I have MyDll.dll and I want access its function Myfunction which is in the form:

> Void pascal Myfunction(BOOL);

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;
void calldll();

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Myfunction(BOOL);

void calldll()
{
    HINSTANCE hDll;
    DWORD dwErrorCode=0;
    LoadMe=LoadLibrary(_T("MyDll.dll"));


    if(hDll!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n DLL loaded successfully \n";
    }

    else
        cout<<"\n Unable to load DLL \n";

    Myfunction sp1=(Myfunction)GetProcAddress(hDll,"Myfunction");


    if(sp1!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n Process loaded successfully \n";
    }
    else
    {
              cout<<"\n Unable to load Process \n";

    }


    FreeLibrary(hDll);

}
```

It is giving error as:

> 1.syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'sp1'
>
> 2.'sp1' : undeclared identifier
>
> 3.syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'

Which I don't understand. Can any help me in this regard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetProcAddress unble to get adress which of the form Void pascal Myfunction(BOOL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003231/getprocaddress-unble-to-get-adress-which-of-the-form-void-pascal-myfunctionbool)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable that is a pointer to a function that returns `void` and accepts a `BOOL` argument:

```
typedef void (pascal *MYFUNCTION_PTR)(BOOL);

MYFUNCTION_PTR fp = (MYFUNCTION_PTR)GetProcAddress(hDll,"Myfunction");
```

For example:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void calldll();

void calldll()
{
    typedef void (pascal *MYFUNCTION_PTR)(BOOL);
    HINSTANCE hDll;

    hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("MyDll.dll"));

    if(hDll!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n DLL loaded successfully \n";

        MYFUNCTION_PTR sp1=(MYFUNCTION_PTR)GetProcAddress(hDll,"Myfunction");

        if(sp1!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"\n Process loaded successfully \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\n Unable to locate function: " << GetLastError() << \n";
        }

        FreeLibrary(hDll);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n Unable to load DLL \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: i have declared the variable already by Myfunction sp1=(Myfunction)GetProcAddress(hDll,"Myfunction).

Comment: by adding this it is printing message as "DLL loaded successfully" "Unable load function" "127"

Comment: Error code 127 means "The specified procedure could not be found." From the earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001619/regarding-getprocaddress/9001711#9001711) @DavidHeffernan mentioned the name decoration due to use of `pascal` calling convention. Did you dump the exports of the DLL using `dumpbin.exe` as I mentioned to see the actual exported name of the function?